# can't create .aspx in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365, administration

I am the global admin and I can't create new aspx forms in the Sharepoint Designer. I am able to create html and css files but if I try to create a new Form in a List it says Server

> Error: access denied.

Comment: are you a site collection administrator?

Comment: When you say the global admin, you mean the farm admin ? You should give yourself permissions to write in the site collection. Also try in the web interface before SharePoint designer.

Comment: can you share images that show how to you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you can't create aspx-files using SharePoint Designer? I did a test on my own environment, and it worked as expected. No error messages at all.

In the site pages, right-click and add a new ASPX file.

[image]

It also works in a simple list

[image]

Please verify that you have sufficient permission for that kind of action.

Comment: That is exactly what I did and then the Error pops up. I should have the sufficient permissions Since I am the global Admin for O365 and the site collection administrator

Comment: @KuKe please check that you are signed in in SPD as the global admin...

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear permission issue with your SharePoint site. Right click your SPD and open as admin and then try to create a new aspx page